# Rails DELETE http method renders page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add a delete functionality to my model. This is what I've come up with, but even though I don't need to render the page to delete something, Rails renders and couldn't find the file for "delete.html.erb"

I am using Ruby 2.0dev and Rails 4.0

My delete link:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", reservation_delete_path(item), :class => "btn btn-small btn-danger", method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
```

My routes file:

```
match 'reservations/delete/:id' => 'reservations#delete', via: :delete, :as => 'reservation_delete'
```

My Controller:

```
def delete
  @current = Reservations.find(params[:id])
  if current_user
    if @current.user_id == current_user.id
      @current.destroy!
      redirect_to reservations_path
    else
      redirect_to reservations_path
    end
  else
    redirect_to reservations_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have some other routes that could interfere? Maybe you have added `resources :reservations` before `match 'reservations/delete/:id' => 'reservations#delete', via: :delete, :as => 'reservation_delete'`? Otherwise try to access `localhost:3000/rails/routes` and se your routes defined there. It could help if you showed us your whole route file.

Comment: Also you could improve your controller (see @Damien Roche's answer), and your routes. You should not use match ever, is't not recommended in Rails 4. Instead use `delete 'reservations/delete/:id', to: 'reservations#delete', as: 'reservation_delete'` or better yet `resources :reservartions, only: :delete` as musicnerd47's suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to duplicate the redirect 3 times for each condition. You can simplify your delete method:

```
def delete
  @current = Reservations.find(params[:id])

  if current_user && @current.user_id == current_user.id
    @current.destroy!
  end

  redirect_to reservations_path
end
```

In your question, if `current_user` isn't available, you have no redirect, and so an implicit render is being run.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is not idiomatic, and there's code you didn't include, so anything could be going wrong. For example, that can't be your whole routes file; there's nothing specifying an index/show/edit/whatever page where your delete button would be. Another example: your action is named `delete` instead of `destroy`. Anyway I can show you an example that works and is much more canonical:

models/reservation.rb:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

controllers/reservations_controller.rb:

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @reservations = Reservation.all
  end

  def destroy
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    @reservation.destroy

    redirect_to reservations_url
  end
end
```

views/reservations/index.html.erb:

```
<% @reservations.each do |reservation| %>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy', reservation, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

(this will literally only show links for deleting corresponding reservations... you'll have to stick `<%= reservation.name %>` or whatever in there if you want to see more info)

config/routes.rb:

```
Howdy::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :reservations, only: [:index, :destroy]
  root 'reservations#index'
end
```

(my app name is howdy)

You have some user auth going on, so add that accordingly. If you're inheriting from a controller that does special user-auth stuff before even hitting the action, that might be why it's trying to render `delete.html.erb`

Comment: Properly the `via: :delete` instead of `method: :delete` as you suggest @Kaleidoscope, that is the problem. But very good suggestion, would improve a lot of the code in the question :)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're missing a return with those redirects, which is actually causing Rails to both execute the redirect *and* try to render the view.

```
return redirect_to reservations_path
```

Comment: Adding "return" didn't change the result.

Comment: No you don't need a return statement, no need at all!

Answer (score -1):

Two things:

The delete (destroy) action is part of resources when you specify it in the routes file. To do this the "rails" way, you might consider having your routes file look more like:

```
resources: :reservations, only: [:delete]
```

... then having the delete link be more like:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', delete_reservation_path(item), :class => 'btn btn-small btn-danger', method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
```

... and then in your controller you can:

```
def destroy
  @current = Reservations.find(params[:id])
  if current_user
    if @current.user_id == current_user.id
      @current.destroy!
      redirect_to reservations_path
    else
      redirect_to reservations_path
    end
  else
    redirect_to reservations_path
  end
end
```

... or you could actually create an rjs template for the delete action to do some fancy javascript work, or you could simply render the view for the index action (faster load the redirecting).

Comment: Your syntax for the route is wrong actually. It should be resources: :reservations, :only => [:delete] also, "and return" doesn't change the result.

Comment: You don't need `and return`.

Comment: But yes @Yagiz, if you use Rails 4 with ruby 2 then the correct syntax would be `resources: :reservations, only: [:delete]`. After ruby 2.0.0 is it recommended to use the new hash syntaz (`key: "value"`) instead of the old (`:key => "value"`).

Comment: Edited to get rid of the return, but the route syntax stands.

Answer (score -2):

My recommendation when you start putting up && gates is to check to see if there is an existing solution. In this case you're probably looking for the functionality that is available in the CanCan gem.

[CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

basically you **load_and_authorize** your users before the controller action and check them through an Ability model. You also get view helpers like

```
if can? :destroy, reservation 
  ... do awesome stuff here ...
```

This will be a far better solution over the long run.

Comment: This isn't a solution to the original question.